# Localhost website to Linux shared server : PHP error/warning

Tags: php, error-log

I did a website on my Windows pc Localhost and everything working fine. I just uploaded my website on a shared Linux server and I see many error/warning in the error_log file that I do not understand.

```
PHP Warning:  session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent
```

The first thing I do in all files is :

```
<?
  session_start();
  ...
```

Second warning:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_real_escape_string(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The second thing I do in all files is to open a connection with the BD

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('bdservice.php');

    $bd = new BDService();
```

I don't understand why I have no error in LocalHost and now I this...

Comment: Error tells you everything you need your username and password is wrong

Comment: `Headers already sent` error means that some kind of output has already gone out to the client and thus session cannot be started.  Check your files for any kind of output that could be getting sent before the `session_start()` call is made.  Even whitespace outside of the php delimiters will cause this to happen.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php) should be used.

Comment: @Dave my username and password are not wrong since I am able to insert into my DB

Comment: @seb they are `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`